# Need help in XSLT transformation for XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I am trying to write an XSLT transformation for the below problem.

Currently, Swipe details are maintained by third party system and receiving in the form of csv. In that,we have multiple IN & OUT records in a day for an employee.

The intention is to get only one record of first swipe In & one record of last swipe Out time by employee, shift & date.

Below is my xml.

How can I write XSLT to get only one Swipe In (which should be first swipeIn in a day &  by shift) and one Swipe out (which should be last swipe out) by Emp, Shift and Day.

But for night shift employees (Code is 1C in XML) change the date of last swipeout since it is night shift (night shift start from 05 PM (today) to 4 AM (tomorrow).

I think, this can be done using group by emp, date & shift but not sure on how to transform the data & for night shift also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>08:53:54</Time>
        <Empid>100</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 2</Gate>
        <InOut>In</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1A</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>10:53:54</Time>
        <Empid>100</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 3</Gate>
        <InOut>Out</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1A</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>11:10:54</Time>
        <Empid>100</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 2</Gate>
        <InOut>In</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1A</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>12:53:54</Time>
        <Empid>100</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 3</Gate>
        <InOut>Out</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1A</Shift>
    </Employees>
        <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>14:00:54</Time>
        <Empid>100</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 2</Gate>
        <InOut>In</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1A</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>18:00:54</Time>
        <Empid>100</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 3</Gate>
        <InOut>Out</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1A</Shift>
    </Employees>    
     <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>17:30:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 2</Gate>
        <InOut>In</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>19:00:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 3</Gate>
        <InOut>Out</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>20:10:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 2</Gate>
        <InOut>In</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-16</Date>
        <Time>23:53:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 3</Gate>
        <InOut>Out</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
        <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-17</Date>
        <Time>01:30:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 2</Gate>
        <InOut>In</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-17</Date>
        <Time>03:00:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 3</Gate>
        <InOut>Out</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
        </Employees>
        <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-17</Date>
        <Time>03:30:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 2</Gate>
        <InOut>In</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <Date>2019-12-17</Date>
        <Time>04:00:54</Time>
        <Empid>101</Empid>
        <Gate>B-1a Main Door 3</Gate>
        <InOut>Out</InOut>
        <Remark>Successful</Remark>
        <Shift>1C</Shift>
    </Employees>
</Data>
```

Output should be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1rTa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the grouping from the similar question, only output two rows of data for each group:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
      <table>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Time</th>
                  <th>EmpId</th>
                  <th>InOut</th>
                  <th>Shift</th>
                  <th>Comment</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="Employees" composite="yes" 
              group-by="Empid, 
                        if (Shift != '1C') 
                        then 
                          xs:date(Date) 
                        else if (xs:time(Time) lt xs:time('08:00:00'))
                        then 
                          xs:date(Date) - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')
                        else 
                          xs:date(Date), 
                        Shift">
              <tbody>
                  <xsl:variable name="min-dateTime"
                    select="min(current-group()/xs:dateTime(Date || 'T' || Time))"/>
                  <xsl:variable name="max-dateTime"
                    select="max(current-group()/xs:dateTime(Date || 'T' || Time))"/>
                  <tr>
                      <td>{format-dateTime($min-dateTime, '[M]-[D]-[Y]')}</td>
                      <td>{format-dateTime($min-dateTime, '[H01]:[m01]:[s01]')}</td>
                      <td>{current-grouping-key()[1]}</td>
                      <td>In</td>
                      <td>{current-grouping-key()[3]}</td>
                      <td>{Shift} Schedule In Time</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>{format-dateTime($max-dateTime, '[M]-[D]-[Y]')}</td>
                      <td>{format-dateTime($max-dateTime, '[H01]:[m01]:[s01]')}</td>
                      <td>{current-grouping-key()[1]}</td>
                      <td>Out</td>
                      <td>{current-grouping-key()[3]}</td>
                      <td>{Shift} - Schedule Out Time</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWRAp4/1

Comment: Thank you so much Martin. Seems it is written using html i think...Can you pls help in xml/xslt since i have to use in workday.

Comment: @Buddi, the question asks about transforming the XML presented with XSLT, that XSLT is posted in my answer. The result format is HTML, the question didn't indicate which format, as HTML is the usual result format to display tables I have used HTML.